# Mouseover on leaflet markers gives Error layer.setStyle is not a function

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have some markers on my map and on mouseover I want to display information in the L.control. Something similar to this [example](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/)On giving style to my L.control in the `highlightFeature()` It throws an error at layer.setStyle is not a function. What am I doing wrong or is there a work around.

```
var info = L.control();

info.onAdd = function (map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
    this.update();
    return this._div;
  };

  info.update = function (props) {
    console.log(props)
    this._div.innerHTML = 'bjkbjk';
  };

function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
    console.log('hey')
   layer.setStyle({
      weight: 5,
      color: '#666',
      dashArray: '',
      fillOpacity: 0.7
    });
    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
      layer.bringToFront();
    }
    console.log(layer.feature.properties);
    info.update(layer.feature.properties);
  }
 function resetHighlight(e) {
    //stateLayer.resetStyle(e.target);
    info.update();
  }

function zoomToFeature(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
      mouseover: highlightFeature,
      mouseout: resetHighlight,
      click: zoomToFeature
    });
  }
subset_layer = L.geoJson(subsetCollection,{onEachFeature: onEachFeature});
```

Comment: Check the `mouseover` event - is the `target` what you think it is (ie a geoJSON vector layer) ?

Comment: sorry, I could not understand what are you asking e to do?could you please elaborate

Comment: Inspect the layer object you get in the  `highlightFeature()` function - is it the layer you're expecting?

Comment: Yes, it is. Is it because of the markers? I found this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204144/bringtofront-bringtoback-on-l-geojson-problem

Comment: Can I update and style L.info in  subset_layer.on('mouseover',...)?

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the issue a work around is check if layer has the method propertiy

`if (typeof layer.setStyle === 'function')`

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you make a proper reference of `leaflet.js` lib files in your project.

`setStyle` is a [method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#path-setstyle) of that library.

I've found a promised tutorial here:
https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/

Please check that you'd include this script reference.

```
<!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-nMMmRyTVoLYqjP9hrbed9S+FzjZHW5gY1TWCHA5ckwXZBadntCNs8kEqAWdrb9O7rxbCaA4lKTIWjDXZxflOcA=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
```

Comment: Thnaks. But it did not help!!